# Friction on inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, friction

Hey I want to find the force of the friction of an object that slip on a inclined plane. The only thing I know is that the object has a 5N gravitational force. I don’t understand how can I do that because I don’t have any distance. I thought that it was the same force as the gravitional force but it seems false. [image]

Comment: Did you say the object is slipping down the incline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need distance. Kinetic friction $f_k$ is not about distance.

Kinetic friction (called [Amontons' Law](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/courses/forces-3/lessons/kinetic-friction-models/)) has the formula:
$$f_k=\mu_kn$$

In your diagram, you have already figured out that the perpendicular component of the gravitational force $mg$ is $mg\cos\theta$.** The normal force is equal to this component (we know this from [Newton's 1st law](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/courses/force-2/lessons/newtons-1st-law-no-change/) in the perpendicular direction). So, the kinetic friction is:

$$f_k=\mu_k \underbrace{mg\cos\theta}_n$$

You've mentioned that the gravitational force is 5 N, so $mg=5\,\mathrm N$. We can plug this in:

$$f_k=5\,\mathrm N\cdot \mu_k \cos\theta$$

Done. All you have to know now is the friction coefficient $\mu_k$ (depends on the surfaces) and the inclination angle $\theta$ (depends on the setup).

---

<sup>** Note that your diagram is slightly misleading. The two $mg\cos\theta$ and $mg\sin\theta$ forces are components of the $mg$ force (the weight). You should not show all these on the same diagram, but only either the two components **or** the one weight force</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From your drawing, the frictional force $f = mgsin\theta$ if the object is stationary.  If the object is slipping then $f < mgsin\theta$ and mg = 5 N.
On your drawing, which is correct, the frictional force must balance the force pulling the block down the inclined plane for the system to be stationary. If the block is sliding down the plane that tells you the frictional force is less than the force pulling the block down the plane.  Since no numbers were given except mg of object then all we can say is f < than force pulling block down the plane.